# Error in Image resizing JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am resizing image before upload with JavaScript library the link is here https://gist.github.com/dcollien/312bce1270a5f511bf4a It has successfully created the blob.My html form is here:

```
<form action="/" class="data-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $form['title']->renderLabel(); ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $form['title']->render(); ?>
        <?php   echo $form['title']->renderError(); ?>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $form['patient_name']->renderLabel(); ?> </td>
        <td><?php
          echo $form['patient_name']->render();
          echo $form['patient_name']->renderError(); ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $form['thumbnail']->renderLabel(); ?> </td>
        <td><?php
          echo $form['thumbnail']->render();
          echo $form['thumbnail']->renderError(); ?>
        </td>
          <td><img id="preview">
          </td>
    </tr>
  <input class="button" type="Submit" value="Save" />
  </form>
```

My JavaScript code is here:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('clinic_stories_thumbnail').onchange = function(evt) {
    ImageTools.resize(this.files[0], {
        width: 300, // maximum width
        height: 250 // maximum height
    }, function(blob, didItResize) {
        // didItResize will be true if it managed to resize it, otherwise false (and will return the original file as 'blob')
        document.getElementById('preview').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        $("#clinic_stories_thumbnail").attr('value',blob);
    });
};
```

I am stuck how to upload the resized blob to server. I have appended the blob with input field through its value attribute. But the field does not get this and the form is submitted with the original image.So please advice how should I send the blob with same POST request. I don't want to submit a separate request for the blob. I want to submit the blob to server with the existing post request.

Comment: is this full text of your HTML?
look in your script $("#clinic_stories_thumbnail").attr('value',blob);
this Id is call from a input type this could use for submission the form

Comment: @AmranurRahman yes this is full text of html.